# Kubernetes does not start the service once deployed the container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, haproxy

I am trying to create a Haproxy in a Kubernetes cluster. So far so good, I manage to create the Docker Image and add the haproxy details.
I am able to deploy it in kubernetes, but once deployed, all pods have 0/1 available because the haproxy service does not start.

Am I missing something here?

This is the docker image that I use:

```
FROM haproxy:1.7

RUN groupadd haproxy && useradd -g haproxy haproxy

COPY haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

CMD touch /var/log/haproxy.log && chmod 777 /var/log/haproxy.log

CMD service rsyslog start && service haproxy start && aproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Comment: what do the logs say

Comment: What does `kubectl describe <pod-name>` says?

Comment: That Dockerfile looks slightly odd to me.  (Two CMDs is always a bug, and as a general rule `service` doesn't work in Docker.)  Could you store the config file in a Kubernetes ConfigMap, and run the unmodified `haproxy:1.7` image?

Comment: OK, I understand that the command "service haproxy start" does not exist in Docker. In this case, how can I ensure that the service will start when the pod will be created?

Comment: This is what I have for the pod created:ubuntu@rl-kube:~$ kubectl describe pod ```haproxy-88f55c778-tmlpw
...
    Command:
      /bin/bash
      -ce
      tail -f /dev/null
...
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
...
  Warning  Unhealthy  22s (x17458 over 1d)  kubelet, rl-cube-node-2  Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 10.244.2.158:1936: connect: connection refused```

Comment: I am solving this by connecting to the pod and run "service haproxy start"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the haproxy published in dockerhub.
You are overriding the CMD defined in the base image.
CMD ["haproxy", "-f", "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]

You dont run "service" inside docker containers.

If you look at the base image all it does is run haproxy command.  By default haproxy runs in the background and in order to make it run in foreground make sure you comment out the 'daemon' in your haproxy.cfg file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I manage to solve the problem by removing the command from the deployment file.

Thanks a lot